# Source tree does not ignoring specific pods file

Tags: ios, xcode, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

When trying to ignore the pod files i am editing the gitignore file and the line that i write there is *pods/* yet it doesn't  ignore all of them:
[image]

Tried also to ignore the specific folder but no success.
Any ideas?

Comment: they might already be being tracked by git. try removing the git references `git rm -r -f --cached Pods/*`. this would remove them from git but not locally

Comment: 1. is that a dangerous manoeuvre? 
2. can you elaborate what did you meant  by"they are tracked by git"?

Comment: 1. no, --cached only removes it from git, not from your local machine so you can always add them again, if you wished to. 2. git may already know of these files from a previous add operation

Comment: btw... `pods/` in your `.gitignore` file should be `Pods/`

Comment: Sorry it is Pods/.
Tried git rm -r -f --cached Pods/* and got this:

 fatal: pathspec 'Pods/ActiveLabel' did not match any files and got 
fatal: pathspec 'Pods/ActiveLabel' did not match any files

Comment: you got that from the git command? personally if I was you I would delete the contents of your Pods folder and run pod install again.

Comment: Did so:rm -rf Pods
and then pod install yet this showing

Comment: still showing unstaged files?. your gitignore file is actually called `.gitignore` isn't it? (dot gitignore)

Comment: Indeed still showing the upstages files (same files).
and yes it calls .gitignore(and its working because it is ignoring 282 pod files except the one you see )